# Ionic white screen on IOS startup

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing an app with Ionic in version 3 but I'm having a problem with the build for IOS, just for IOS.

For several days I researched and did not find a solution to my problem, able to compile the last two versions without problem, but now that I need to release another version, but it is not going.

> Only the build for iOS is giving trouble.

### The problem

After the build, testing on a real device, the application enters the splashscreen and exits, entering a white screen that does not come out at all.

This occurs only in the build with the `--prod` flag. When I run in debug mode it works perfectly, with livereload and everything else.

### Information

In the XCode console the only thing I see is all startup, and when the app is locked, on the white screen I see: `TIC Read Status [10: 0x0]: 1:57` and `TIC Read Status [11: 0x0]: 1:57`

Any attempt to help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist version is 1.3.0 need to uninstall and needs to install the latest version cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 . Then ionic cordova platform rm ios, ionic cordova platform add ios, ionic cordova build ios.

Comment: The plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist already in 1.3.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and nothing seemed to be working. 
In the end, I added the browser as a platform.

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

Then, I tried to run that as production and it was from there, that I was able to diagnose the problem more, because the errors were shown then in the console.

```
ionic cordova run browser --prod --release
```

I didn't have much luck with XCode showing me and real errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue recently. Are you using ionic SplashScreen plugin? Can you try performing a clean installation after deleting node_modules, platforms and plugins directories.

If it didn't work update your app.component.ts like this.

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

export class MyApp {
   ...
   constructor(... public splashScreen: SplashScreen, ...) {

   this.initializeApp();

}

initializeApp() {

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    ...

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    }, 2000);

    ...

  });
}
```

In your config.xml set this perference.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
```